# Is Firebase Storage .overall_export_metadata automatically generated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to revive an old project that I haven't work or maintained in a long time. Upon visiting Firebase Cloud Storage section I saw this folder named in this format `/2023-03-06T04:18:10_77735`. Upon searching I saw this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_data) but I don't remember doing any importation before so my question is does Firebase automatically do this from time to time, moreover is it safe do delete it? I saw that there is an update on Cloud Firestore about PITR but I don't think that is also available with Cloude Storage.

Comment: I've never seen such an auto-generated folder on any of my Cloud Storage for Firebase buckets, so it seems unlikely that Firebase generated it in yours.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it safe to delete it since I don't know what to do with it?